# WTForms creating unwated text in template

Tags: python, html, flask, wtforms

I'm using a SelectField and a SelectMultipleField in my template and it is creating the form elements just fine but there is unwanted text on the page.  Below the SelectMultipleField in the browser I'm seeing this:

```
" multiple name="genres" placeholder="Genres, separated by commas" required>
Alternative
Blues
Classical
Country
Electronic
Folk
Funk
Hip-Hop
Heavy Metal
Instrumental
Jazz
Musical 
Theatre
Pop
Punk
R&B
Reggae
Rock n Roll
Soul
Other
```

And below a text field I'm seeing a list of states from an above SelectField form element.  I'm wondering why I'm seeing all this unwanted text on the page.  This is my relevant code:

forms.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField, SelectMultipleField, DateTimeField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, AnyOf, URL

class VenueForm(Form):
    name = StringField(
        'name', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    city = StringField(
        'city', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    state = SelectField(
        'state', validators=[DataRequired()],
        choices=[
            ('AL', 'AL'),
            ('AK', 'AK'),
            ('AZ', 'AZ'),
            ('AR', 'AR'),
            ('CA', 'CA'),
            ('CO', 'CO'),
            ('CT', 'CT'),
            ('DE', 'DE'),
            ('DC', 'DC'),
            ('FL', 'FL'),
            ('GA', 'GA'),
            ('HI', 'HI'),
            ('ID', 'ID'),
            ('IL', 'IL'),
            ('IN', 'IN'),
            ('IA', 'IA'),
            ('KS', 'KS'),
            ('KY', 'KY'),
            ('LA', 'LA'),
            ('ME', 'ME'),
            ('MT', 'MT'),
            ('NE', 'NE'),
            ('NV', 'NV'),
            ('NH', 'NH'),
            ('NJ', 'NJ'),
            ('NM', 'NM'),
            ('NY', 'NY'),
            ('NC', 'NC'),
            ('ND', 'ND'),
            ('OH', 'OH'),
            ('OK', 'OK'),
            ('OR', 'OR'),
            ('MD', 'MD'),
            ('MA', 'MA'),
            ('MI', 'MI'),
            ('MN', 'MN'),
            ('MS', 'MS'),
            ('MO', 'MO'),
            ('PA', 'PA'),
            ('RI', 'RI'),
            ('SC', 'SC'),
            ('SD', 'SD'),
            ('TN', 'TN'),
            ('TX', 'TX'),
            ('UT', 'UT'),
            ('VT', 'VT'),
            ('VA', 'VA'),
            ('WA', 'WA'),
            ('WV', 'WV'),
            ('WI', 'WI'),
            ('WY', 'WY'),
        ]
    )
    address = StringField(
        'address', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    phone = StringField(
        'phone'
    )
    image_link = StringField(
        'image_link'
    )
    genres = SelectMultipleField(
        # TODO implement enum restriction
        'genres', validators=[DataRequired()],
        choices=[
            ('Alternative', 'Alternative'),
            ('Blues', 'Blues'),
            ('Classical', 'Classical'),
            ('Country', 'Country'),
            ('Electronic', 'Electronic'),
            ('Folk', 'Folk'),
            ('Funk', 'Funk'),
            ('Hip-Hop', 'Hip-Hop'),
            ('Heavy Metal', 'Heavy Metal'),
            ('Instrumental', 'Instrumental'),
            ('Jazz', 'Jazz'),
            ('Musical Theatre', 'Musical Theatre'),
            ('Pop', 'Pop'),
            ('Punk', 'Punk'),
            ('R&B', 'R&B'),
            ('Reggae', 'Reggae'),
            ('Rock n Roll', 'Rock n Roll'),
            ('Soul', 'Soul'),
            ('Other', 'Other'),
        ]
    )
    facebook_link = StringField(
        'facebook_link', validators=[URL()]
    )
```

new_venue.html:

```
{% extends 'layouts/main.html' %}
{% block title %}New Venue{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form method="post" class="form">
      <h3 class="form-heading">List a new venue <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" title="Back to homepage"><i class="fa fa-home pull-right"></i></a></h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        {{ form.name(class_ = 'form-control', autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>City & State</label>
          <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.city(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='City', autofocus = true) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.state(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='State', autofocus = true) }}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        {{ form.address(class_ = 'form-control', autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          {{ form.phone(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='xxx-xxx-xxxx', autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="genres">Genres</label>
        <small>Ctrl+Click to select multiple</small>
        {{ form.genres(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='Genres, separated by commas', id=form.genres, autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="genres">Facebook Link</label>
          {{ form.facebook_link(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='http://', id=form.state, autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Create Venue" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

app.py:

```
@app.route('/venues/create', methods=['GET'])
def create_venue_form():
  form = VenueForm()
  return render_template('forms/new_venue.html', form=form)
```

Why is the page generating this unwanted text?

Comment: I haven't tested anything but something stands out here: `{{ form.genres(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='Genres, separated by commas', id=form.genres, autofocus = true) }}` you pass the entire `form.genres` field to the `id` param of the renderer, perhaps that should be `id=form.genres.id`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution in SuperShoot's comment above worked for me.  Change `id=form.genre` to `id=form.genre.id` and `id=form.state` to `id=form.state.id`.

I had previously simply deleted `id=form.genre` and `id=form.state`, which also solved the display problem, but seems to have caused other problems.